# python Reportlab, add two tables side by side in pdf

Tags: python-2.7, reportlab

I am trying to insert two tables in the pdf using python reportlab.
Number of rows in the second table are less than first table.

But the horizontal position of the two tables is not matching.
Some empty space coming on the second table.

How can I remove this space so that both the tables will come horizontally aligned?

```
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, inch
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("simple_table_grid.pdf", pagesize=letter)

elements = []

data= [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
   ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14'],
   ['20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
   ['30', '31', '32', '33', '34']]

data1= [['00', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
   ['10', '11', '12', '13', '14']]

t1=Table(data,5*[0.4*inch], 4*[0.4*inch],hAlign='LEFT')

t1.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN',(1,1),(-2,-2),'RIGHT'),
                   ('TEXTCOLOR',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.red),
                   ('VALIGN',(0,0),(0,-1),'TOP'),
                   ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(0,-1),colors.blue),
                   ('ALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                   ('VALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                   ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,-1),(-1,-1),colors.green),
                   ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                   ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                   ]))

t2=Table(data1,5*[0.4*inch], 2*[0.4*inch],hAlign='RIGHT')

t2.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN',(1,1),(-2,-2),'RIGHT'),
                   ('TEXTCOLOR',(1,1),(-2,-2),colors.red),
                   ('VALIGN',(0,0),(0,-1),'TOP'),
                   ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,0),(0,-1),colors.blue),
                   ('ALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                   ('VALIGN',(0,-1),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
                   ('TEXTCOLOR',(0,-1),(-1,-1),colors.green),
                   ('INNERGRID', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                   ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.25, colors.black),
                   ]))
t = [[t1,t2]]

temp = Table(t)                  

elements.append(temp)

doc.build(elements)
```

Comment: It's not clear to me, what you want. Do you want t1 and t2 to be on the same line (t1 on the left, t2 on the right) and you are concerned with the space inbetween t1 and t2?
Or do you want t1 on top and t2 on bottom? In this case "horizontally aligned" would make more sense to me.

Comment: Yes I want t1 and t2 on the same line.
but what is happening, when t2 contains less number of rows than t1, then t1 and t2 are not starting from the same line.

Comment: Okay, then you want to align t1 and t2 *vertically*, right? You can align them on the top line by adding the style `TableStyle([('VALIGN', (0,0), (-1,-1), 'TOP')])` to the table `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

To have 2 tables horizontal, i don't think it's possible to do it with reportLab.
I kind had the same problem, i found a way to do resolve it.
I create only one table to represent both tables, and i hide the grid between the 2, so it look like it's 2 tables. With that solution you can position the 2 tables the way you want.
My setStyle() looks like that

```
        t.setStyle(TableStyle([
                           ('GRID', (0,0), (4,1), 0.5, colors.black),
                            ('ALIGN',(1,1),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
                            ('BACKGROUND',(0,0),(4,0),colors.lightgrey),
                            ('BACKGROUND',(3,3),(3,5),colors.lightgrey),
                            ('BOX',(3,3),(3,5),0.5,colors.black),
                            ('BOX',(4,3),(4,5),0.5,colors.black)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

well, there is a workaround for it.
You can add your tables in another table with two columns and a single row.
Something like this..

```
    data= [(t1, t2)]
    t = Table(data, [250, 250])
    t.setStyle(TableStyle([
               ('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'TOP')
               ]))
```